# Adding a new line (/n) to a textblurp under condition using python

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, text-processing

I'm currently tryng to split text especially where there is no space after the '.'(dot). The df is a csv file.

My current code (don't mind the spaces please) :

```
for i in df['blurb']:
  try:
    df.loc[i,'blurb'] = df.loc[i,'blurb'].replace('.A', '.\nA')
  except:
    pass 
...
  try:
    df.loc[i,'blurb'] = df.loc[i,'blurb'].replace('.Z', '.\nZ')
  except:
   pass
```

and this for every letter from the alphabet, since i' looking to put a /n [nem line] after every such dots.

the result is the same as the original (it does not want to save over the original). If i create another column, [blurb2], it gives the same outcome as the original blurb column. I've already looked for a few hours on this site for answers , but nothing seems to work [no error messages though] ... This is driving me crazy...

Anyone have any tips ? Thanks a mill in advance !

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert a newline after a dot that has a non-whitespace after it you can use

```py
df['blurb'] = df['blurb'].str.replace(r'\.(?=\S)', '\\g<0>\n')
```

Note here

- `\.` - matches a dot char that is followed with
- `(?=\S)` - any char other than whitespace. Since it is a regex lookahead, its pattern is only checked for, but does not get consumed.

The `\g<0>` is the whole match value matched by the regex.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thanks a mll for the respoinse! Learned alot. One more QQ, is there a way to make it so that it only adds a new line when there is a capital behind the "dot"? there are some ."com" in the text file and it gives rather a weird result.

Comment: @MatthiasDeMaertelaere An uppercase letter can be easily defined as `[A-Z]`. So, use `df['blurb'].str.replace(r'\.(?=[A-Z])', '\\g<0>\n')`